# Delete item in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How to find and delete only one element in a list in Python?

```
# Example:deleting only the first (1,2) in the list
a = [(4, 5), (1, 2), (7, 5), (1, 2), (5, 2)]
# result expected
a = [(4, 5), (7, 5), (1, 2), (5, 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `list.remove()` method to remove the first occurrence, in-place:

```
a.remove((1, 2))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [(4, 5), (1, 2), (7, 5), (1, 2), (5, 2)]
>>> a.remove((1, 2))
>>> a
[(4, 5), (7, 5), (1, 2), (5, 2)]
```

See the [*Mutable Sequence Types* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> `s.remove(x)`
>   same as `del s[s.index(x)]`

and `s.index()` only ever finds the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Be blessed.

Answer (score -1):

Hello if you want to delete any thing in lists

use these codes

```
mylist.pop(element_order) #mylist stands for your list and
#element_order stands for the order of element is the list and if it is the 
#first element it will be 0
```

or you can use

```
mylist.remove(the_element)
```

note that in the pop it is a method not a list

```
mylist.pop(0)
print mylist
```

dont use

```
mylist = mylist.pop(0)
```

Comment: Lists don't *have* a `delete` method. `mylist.pop()` deletes elements *by index*, not by value, which is what the OP is asking for, and also returns the removed element, making it do more work than a simple `del listobject[index]`.

Comment: iam sorry i meant remove